# How to select deep learning library and CNN architecture?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new in the deep learning, and I want to use convolutional neural networks (CNN) for image recognition (biometric images).

I would like to use pre-trained CNN architecture and use a python programming language.

- How can I select the suitable CNN architecture (VGGNet or GoogleNet ...), is there a preferable CNN architecture?
- What do you think is the best library to do this work, how can I select the suitable library?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can use tensorflow-slim. They have a library of many top pre-trained CNN models that you can use directly or fine-tune easily on your dataset. I think the training time depends on your hardware and amount of data you have.

Comment: Thanks for replaying, I will use a computer with a high GPU. Are there any factors other than the amount of data?

Comment: Yes, how you access your data is also important. Suppose, if you have a large amount of data then in that case, try making .tfrecord or .hdf5 files of your data before training. This will make your data access faster. Otherwise, accessing large data from the hard disk will be a slow process.